# How to create an 'Add' and 'Remove' control dynamically with InfoPath designer 2013?

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-server

I am new to SharePoint and have been given the task of designing a form in Infopath 2013 described in the following scenario:

- Select a responsible, Resp.type, then click "Add". Then I will get a result as outlined below (in the picture) I also want to be able to delete any rows I added.

[image]

The problem is Infopath suported repeating table, but it wasn't show that menu when I edit a form of Sharepoint List. I also don't know how to make this in "Sharepoint List"

How can I make this in infoPath 2013?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is a parent/child relationship. This cannot be created in a single SharePoint list.

InfoPath supports repeating tables, but not in list forms.

You can create a relational parent/child setup in SharePoint and you can use JavaScript to connect the two lists in a form or a page. Using just InfoPath, though, it is not possible to write to another list from an InfoPath list form. You would need code to achieve that and IP list forms don't support code.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, can you give me a reference of example that similar my problem. Thanks

Comment: try http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2010/12/16/creating-a-sharepoint-parentchild-list-relationshipndash-sharepoint-2010-edition.aspx